# How to fix 'Access violation at address 00660938 in module Project1.exe. Read of address 00000150.' in Indy (Delphi 10.3 Rio)

Tags: delphi, post, indy

I'm am writing a software which will decrypt JDownloader DLC files. This program will send the dlc file to "http://dcrypt.it/decrypt/upload" with POST request and will get decoded links as response.

This is my code which throws that error:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
    Stream: TStringStream;
    Params: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
    HTTP: TIdHTTP;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  Params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  Params.AddFile('File1', 'D:\3fcaa401f8f3ebe32fb93cb607ecadd01ee954ed.dlc', 'application/octet-stream');
  HTTP.Post('http://dcrypt.it/decrypt/upload', Params, Stream);
  ShowMessage(Stream.DataString);
end;
```

When I debug my program, Delphi IDE shows these in IdHTTP.pas:

```
function TIdCustomHTTP.GetRequest: TIdHTTPRequest;
begin
 Result := FHTTPProto.Request; //This line is highlighted.
end;
```

So, what should I do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: @Zam I have added Indy HTTP component to the form; but it still throws "Bad Request" error.

Comment: On a side note, I don't recommend using a `TStringStream` to receive the response, especially when no `Encoding` is specified. `Post()` has an overload that returns the response as a `String`, use that instead, eg: `ShowMessage(HTTP.Post('http://dcrypt.it/decrypt/upload', Params));`

Answer (score 6):

You are not initializing the HTTP component. Since it is a global variable it will be automatically initialized to `nil`.

When you call `HTTP.Post('http://dcrypt.it/decrypt/upload', Params, Stream);` it will not break immediately at the place of call. You are calling it on a `nil` reference, so it causes the AV as soon as it accesses some inner field or attempts to call a virtual method.

You have to construct the HTTP component before you use it:

```
HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  ...
finally
  HTTP.Free;
end;
```

---

Also, good practice is that you should avoid using global variables. You can and should declare all the necessary variables as local. And make sure that you release everything after you are done.

Comment: as well as 1) release TStringStream 2) release TIdMultiPartFormDataStream

Comment: @Zam I was just typing that :)